# ANOVA on percentages

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model, proportion, percentage

**Please read edit 3 first**

I am trying to find out the significant factors in a dataset of percentages, a sample of which are below. The difficulty is that the data violates the assumptions of ANOVA, and most of the data are fairly close to 100%.

Please note that glm + binary would not work: the samples used to calculate each proportion are not independent. I do have access to the denominator, if that helps.

Any direction where to start? I've read quite a few things here and elsewhere (notably trying to use some transformation such as arcsin, etc...) and also some other methods I never heard of ("contingency table approaches"). As in a "textbook ANOVA" I would like to know which factors are significant, and how much of the variability they explain.

```
data = c(0.79,0.98,0.95,0.95,1,0.98,0.99,0.97,0.99,0.99,0.98,0.99,0.99,0.94,0.94,  
0.86,0.84,0.86,0.97,0.96,0.53,0.87,0.97,0.81,0.99,1,0.99,0.87,0.98,0.97,0.93,0.8,  
0.7,0.94,0.89,0.98,0.89,0.98,0.96,0.98)
```

**Edit:** sorry for the lack of clarity. Here's how my percentages are calculated: I basically throw a number of particles (known only a posteriori) in a funnel and count how many make it through/how many remain stuck in the funnel. The percentage is the ratio of the particles having made it through divided by the total number of particles.If a particle which comes at the beginning of the trial remains stuck, the odds of a subsequent particle to remain stuck are higher. As such, I don't think I can apply a generalized linear model, specifying binomial as familly (in R I mean). But again, my statistical insights may be utterly wrong.

**Edit2:** regarding independance, I guess my comment was misleading. Each sample in the vector above is independant from the others. However, as I explain in the edit above, the samples used to calculate each percentage are not.

**Edit3:**
Well, I reckon I probably made a mess of my question, think it may help if I rephrase the problem and show some data (a fraction of my whole dataset). Besides, I have progressed a bit, hopefully in the right direction. I do not know if I should do a full edit of my original question, or even abandon and start anew, I'll add this as an edit for the interest of history (let me know if I should do differently).

My response variable is the percentage of particles having made it through a funnel (the total number of particles is different for each percentage). If a particle at the beginning of the trial remains stuck, the odds of a subsequent particle to remain stuck are higher.

The (potential) explanatory variables are 1) the type of particles, 2) the funnel type, 3) the funnel position and 4) the total number of particles. In a first stage, I want to find which of these actually impact the response variable and by how much.
In a second stage, I would like to use the current dataset as a reference for the analysis of future samples.  Precisely, I would like to know if the percentage of particles having made through the funnel is  significantly different from the reference dataset and by how much.

Plotting the data indicates me that each population may have a different mean and a different variance.

```
# Libraries ####
library(ggplot2)
library(betareg)
library(lmtest)

#Create data####
df5 = structure(list(type = c("Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", 
                              "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type3", "Type3", "Type3", 
                              "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type3", "Type3", "Type3", "Type2", 
                              "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", 
                              "Type1", "Type3", "Type3", "Type3", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", 
                              "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type3", "Type3", "Type3", "Type1", 
                              "Type1", "Type1", "Type3", "Type3", "Type3", "Type2", "Type2", 
                              "Type2", "Type3", "Type3", "Type3", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2"), 
                     funnelType = c("fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", 
                                    "fType1", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", 
                                    "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", 
                                    "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", 
                                    "fType1", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", 
                                    "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType1", "fType1", "fType1", "fType2", 
                                    "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", 
                                    "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2", "fType2"), 
                     position = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", 
                                  "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", 
                                  "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", 
                                  "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", 
                                  "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), 
                     total = c(420L, 293L, 324L, 549L, 
                               527L, 603L, 533L, 571L, 438L, 496L, 534L, 604L, 489L, 360L, 383L, 
                               524L, 560L, 606L, 493L, 513L, 572L, 530L, 527L, 543L, 616L, 471L, 
                               554L, 392L, 530L, 443L, 561L, 529L, 599L, 529L, 481L, 521L, 621L, 
                               567L, 609L, 447L, 398L, 462L, 528L, 574L, 522L, 654L, 531L, 556L, 
                               642L, 569L, 684L, 372L, 540L, 345L), 
                     percentage = c(0.98808, 0.95569, 0.9784, 0.57741, 0.81017, 0.82919, 0.93809, 0.94041, 
                                    0.94744, 0.93352, 0.98129, 0.99006, 0.97339, 0.94728, 0.98695, 
                                    0.9542, 0.84989, 0.92574, 0.79116, 0.92782, 0.98077, 0.96605, 
                                    0.97155, 0.96503, 0.97076, 0.95756, 0.99097, 0.96429, 0.9434, 
                                    0.99097, 0.78253, 0.94518, 0.97664, 0.99056, 0.96261, 0.98273, 
                                    0.88402, 0.96824, 0.92118, 0.95524, 0.97991, 0.9762, 0.83144, 
                                    0.95643, 0.98085, 0.95107, 0.94162, 0.98741, 0.83635, 0.94372, 
                                    0.98099, 0.88447, 0.94817, 0.95365)), 
                .Names = c("type", "funnelType","position", "total", "percentage"), class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(2L, 
                              3L, 4L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 98L, 99L, 
                              100L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 162L, 
                              163L, 164L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 
                              258L, 259L, 260L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 354L, 355L, 
                              356L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 386L, 387L, 388L))

ggplot(df5,aes(x=total,y=percentage))+geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+geom_jitter(aes(col=position))+facet_grid(type~funnelType)
```

It does seem that I am in a situation comparable the dyslexic example in http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/met/11/1/54/. I consequently think that I should be able to apply the same method to analyse my data. To do so I use the package betareg in R (no interactions for the sake of the example).

```
full <- betareg(percentage ~ type+funnelType+position+total|type+funnelType+position+total,data = df5)
summary(full)
```

This yields the results that all explanatory variables but "total" have a significant effect on the mean. From what I know explanatory variables are likely to be significant in large data sets (I have a relatively large number of observastions in my full dataset). How do I judge the magnitude of the effect of each factor? What should I do if two of the explanatory variables are correlated?

In my second stage I want to compare a new sample to the subpopulation in my dataset that has the same predictor values. How should I perform this? Unequal variance t-test?

Comment: I find your second paragraph unclear -- could you explain how something akin to "ANOVA" *could* be okay, yet a binomial GLM would not? What exactly is the dependence you refer to?

Comment: If the data are not independent, then you need to account for that. The data being mostly close to 100% does not, by itself, violate the assumptions of ANOVA - it makes no assumption about the distribution of the dependent variable.  Please give more details of your problem.

Comment: @PeterFlom ANOVA makes no assumptions about the distribution of the dependent variable? Normality? Equal variances?

Comment: How do you not have independence when there are separate sample sizes (denominators)?

Comment: @Alexis it makes assumptions about the distribution of the residuals, not the dependent variable.

Comment: @PeterFlom both oneway ANOVA and repeated measures ANOVA assume normality of outcome and equal variances, and it's not clear to me that user46126 is talking about anything but the repeated measures ANOVA. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alexis No, neither assumes that the outcome is normal; they assume that the residuals are normal.

Comment: @PeterFlom I think that for oneway and repeated measures one cannot have normality of residuals without having normality of data... kinda like not one can't have cotton candy without also having the fluffy parts.

Comment: You certainly can. `set.seed(1234)
sex <- c(rep("M", 500), rep("F", 500))
mweight <- rnorm(500, 200, 17)
fweight <- rnorm(500, 150, 15)
weight <- c(mweight, fweight)

plot(density(weight)) #Not normal

m1 <- lm(weight~sex)
plot(density(m1$residuals)) #Normal`